# package titlesec does not allow expansion of #1 in the \titleformat {<before-code>} in latest version of texlive 2021

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I'm trying to format my section headings using `titlecaps` so I have used the command

```
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont}{\thesection}{.5em}{%
    \titlecap{#1}}
```

which worked for texLive 2017.  Recently, I upgraded to TexLive2021 (for other reasons), and now any `\section` commands fail with  `Illegal parameter number in definition of \the@@@string.`

The log file shows the additional message after the first error of:

```
 You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.
```

which I'm interpreting as not expanding the #1 macro correctly.  Any suggestions?
MWE follows

```
\documentclass{article} % documentclass for TR
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{.5em}{\normalfont\titlecap{#1}}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
Lorem
\section{my head}
citations
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code generates errors in every version of TeX Live I have on my machine (from 2012 to 2021).

The `titlesec` package is clear about this: either use the `explicit` option (but this is rarely necessary) or use the standard feature that the last token in the last mandatory argument to `\titleformat` will be followed by

```
{<the current title>}
```

at point of usage. So, if the last token requires an argument, it finds exactly what it wants.

```
\documentclass{article} % documentclass for TR
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries}{\thesection}{.5em}{\normalfont\titlecap}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
Lorem
\section{my head}
citations
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I found a solution.  The `titlesec` package defines an option `explicit` that enables the expansion of the #1 macro correctly.  So change line 2 above to

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
```

and all works.